# How to set permissions when files not found? Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, installation

I am having so much trouble installing Symfony: I installed the .zip file to the htdocs folder in XAMPP and according to Symfony's config file I need to reset permissions:

1. Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
2. Change the permissions of the "app/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
   I went here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html and tried step 1, resetting the permissions in the terminal and it told me:

chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'app/cache': No such file or directory
chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'app/logs': No such file or directory

So I tried steps 2 and 3. I went to /app_dev.php/ on my local machine and it's still telling me "object not found" 
I have no idea what to do at this point. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*
```

**Setting up Permissions**

```
$ APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod +a "$APACHEUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs

OR

$ APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```